# Upload Local Image With Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: java, image, selenium, input, upload

I have looked at many answers and only found bits and pieces that worked to end up here, so basically I am using selenium to select the file input on the page, then execute some javascript to make it visible, and then send the file path to the keys.

all of this works but when I submit the form the image is not displayed on the final product, e.g. when I click submit and view my post there is no image

Here's my code:

```
WebElement imageUpload = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id=\"FileInputWrapper\"]/input")));
    Thread.sleep(600);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type', 'file');", imageUpload);
    Thread.sleep(600);
    imageUpload.sendKeys(computerHome + "/downloads/testImageFolder/testImage.jpg");
    Thread.sleep(600);
```

After Selenium does this, this appears above the submit image button:

[image: File Input Appears (Previously There Was No Choose File There)]

This means it received my image but for some reason it also did not?
because when I click submit on the post the image is not visible there are no images.

Any ideas are very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us relevant HTML blocks - of the working example and not working one?

Answer (score 0):

Below method will help you too browse the file and select it. Just pass 3 required parameters

1. Element type
2. Element locator
3. File path/resource

Here is the code:

```
/*-------    FileUploading(): This method browse and the upload the selected file    -------*/
    public static void FileUpload(PropertyType ElementType, string Element, string FilePath)
    {
        if (ElementType == PropertyType.Id)
        {
            PropertyCollection.wdriver.FindElement(By.Id(Element)).Click();
        }
        else if (ElementType == PropertyType.XPath)
        {
            PropertyCollection.wdriver.FindElement(By.XPath(Element)).Click();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        SendKeys.SendWait(FilePath);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
     }
```

Comment: Why do we need the second else if, since it is empty?